# Angular - Group HTML Table rows with CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have Implemented this example table with Bootstrap. When I click the button I want to isolate that row, which means that I want to add some gap between the other rows/head. I tried many `CSS` commands found on StackOverflow but none of them worked. I have the knowledge to combine it with Typescript with `(click)`. I mostly want the `CSS` to make it look beautiful.
My Table is generated dynamically with `*ngFor` but for this example I made it static.

```css
body {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.table {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-bordered {
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}


.isolated {
  border-spacing: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  
  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
        <th>Head</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Isolate me!</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="isolated">
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Isolate me!</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td>element</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Isolate me!</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your code attempt at this?

Comment: @AndyG I had added margin-bottom, padding-bottom, border-spacing. But they didn't work. So I erased it to make a clean snippet. Should I put them back in?

Comment: You must demonstrate your attempt otherwise you are just asking someone to write code for you.

Comment: Tables are not really made for that kind of formatting in the first place. Margins don’t _apply_ to table rows or cells, because that would make rather little sense, and would collide with the basic table layout algorithm. Depending on what _exactly_ you want - descriptions is rather vague - you could perhaps emulate a similar effect by cleverly playing with row/cells borders and paddings inside the cells of a row.

Comment: so, @misorude I have to play inside <tr> ?? Can I separate also the borders, so to be clear that it's grouped/isolated?

Comment: Check the answer @Ramesh posted meanwhile, does that come close to what you want?

Answer (score 1):

You will need js support to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.isolate').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('td>div').css({
      'margin': '20px'
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.table {
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #aaa;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table-bordered {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.table-bordered td {
  border: none !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.table-bordered td>div {
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  padding: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
    <th>Head</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary isolate">Isolate me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary isolate">Isolate me!</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div>element</div>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary isolate">Isolate me!</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It's close enough to my thought. But I would like the vertical borders separated from the others and not to hide the inside borders

Comment: So you need to change your entire html structure and avoid bootstrap since the border is set to `td` and `td` don't accept `margin` property but supports `padding`. So you can't separate td by setting `padding` because the border will remain the same.

Comment: so, how to separate the border? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Antifa Now you can style the separation as you wanted

Answer (score 0):

You can't use *margin* on `<tr>`. *Padding* can be used but if you don't want to use it a possible workaround is to *hide and show* (or *create and destroy*) empty rows above and underneath the button that was pressed. Of course, you have to use *JavaScript* because you need to implement some logic.